# Signing dll and exe files through powershell script issue

Tags: powershell

I have a script that iterates through files in a folder and signs all .dll and .exe files with a code signing certificate. 
My issue is that among the 30 or so files out of which 2 files are .exe all are signed correctly and signatures are valid save for one which was singed but reports an error with the certificate. When i do `Get-AuthenticodeSignature` on it the return value is `HashMismatch`.
And afterwards if i do a `Set-AuthenticodeSignature` manually it signes the file and there is no `HashMismatch`.
I have tried sveral ways of iterating through the folder ad signing files and the issue still remains that whenever i try to sign that specific file through the script it always returns `HashMismatch`.

the script is
`foreach ($file in $files)
    {$signed =  Get-AuthenticodeSignature $file
        if($signed -ne "Valid" )
        {
            $result = Set-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath $file.FullName -Certificate $Cert -IncludeChain "All" -HashAlgorithm "sha256" -TimeStampServer "http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll"
            if($result.Status -eq "Valid")           {
                {Write-Host "$file success"}
            }
            else
            { Write-Host "$file $result.StatusMessage "}
        }
    }`

Comment: _"the script is "_ ??? where?

Comment: Sorry dunno why it did not post with code initially i edited the question now

Comment: The ps1 script example above is not complete and cannot be run as the objects '$files' and '$Cert' are not declared.